# Does Storing Sessions In Database Prevent Hijacking/Fixation

Tags: php, session, session-hijacking, session-fixation

After many hours of frustration, I've managed to write a script that stores PHP sessions in the database. My question is, does this prevent session hijacking and/or fixation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. But if you are storing the associated IP, and even better, the mac address, then yes.

Comment: @TimWithers I actually stored the IP and the user agent, I take it that isn't enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Its just a different datastore.